# API capabilities - Can I create and present a custom News Feed of updates?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I do not want to show the user their news feed.

I do want to show them a "custom" news feed from the pages I've selected.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a lot of parsing, merging, and formatting, but, yes, you can do this by pulling the feeds you want to use, merging their items by, and presenting to the user on your site.